# How do I display information about all encountered symlinks in a given path?

Tags: symlink

How do I obtain a description of all encountered symlinks for the given path?

Expecting output like this:

```
$ linksinfo ~/.nix-profile/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so
/home is a directory
/home/nix is a directory
/home/nix/.nix-profile -> /home/nix/.nix-profile -> /nix/var/nix/profiles/default
/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/lib is a directory
/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so -> /nix/store/33xkmx1f1040s5nb15x7hx2cqmyw1jyi-qt-5.3.1/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so
/nix/store/33xkmx1f1040s5nb15x7hx2cqmyw1jyi-qt-5.3.1/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so -> libQt5OpenGL.so.5.3.1
/nix/store/33xkmx1f1040s5nb15x7hx2cqmyw1jyi-qt-5.3.1/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.3.1 is a file
```

Comment: Can you please explain your output a bit more. It doesn't make total sense. You're giving `linksinfo` a path to a file, but what do you expect it to do then?

Comment: Scan all components of the path (in this case, `/`, `home`, `nix`, `.nix-profile`, `lib`, `libQt5OpenGL.so`) and output destinations of all encountered symlinks, including when them does "chain". It should provide answer to the question "How many symbolic links get dereferenced when I access this path".

Comment: Is this for a school project? It's fine if it is, but pls state it as such and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: @slm, No, I'm just looking for a tool that makes navigating in a labyrinth of symlinks (in Nix they are used heavily) simpler, without manual `ls -ld`. Before writing a tool myself I often "lookup" it using StackExchange.

Comment: @not a problem, just had to ask. There isn't a tool that will do this directly. The closest tool to doing anything related to this is called `readlink`.

Comment: @slm, It process only the final link. Also in case of chained link it shows only the final destination.

Comment: That's correct. As I said it's the only tool that I'm aware of that does any evaluations w/ links.

Comment: There's also the tool `symlink` as I've discussed it here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99159/is-there-an-algorithm-to-decide-if-a-symlink-loops/99166#99166

Answer (score 1):

Lets create simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash            

mypath=$1
while [[ "${#mypath}" -gt 1 ]]; do
      file "$mypath"
      mypath="$(dirname $mypath)"
done
```

---

Test:

```
$ ./linksinfo /usr/src/linux/kernel/../../../../bin/sh
/usr/src/linux/kernel/../../../../bin/sh: symbolic link to `bash'
/usr/src/linux/kernel/../../../../bin: directory
/usr/src/linux/kernel/../../../..: directory
/usr/src/linux/kernel/../../..: directory
/usr/src/linux/kernel/../..: directory
/usr/src/linux/kernel/..: directory
/usr/src/linux/kernel: directory
/usr/src/linux: symbolic link to `linux-3.14.14-gentoo'
/usr/src: directory
/usr: directory
```

---

**Edit**

This does not check/show all path components, but the output in you question doesn't do this either. For example after

```
/home/nix/.nix-profile -> /nix/var/nix/profiles/default
```

it is possible that any of `/nix`, `/nix/var/`, `/nix/var/nix`, `/nix/var/nix/profiles` or `/nix/var/nix/profiles/default` is a link itself. However your output skips this and checks only `/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/lib`. Similar thing happens with

```
/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so -> /nix/store/33xkmx1f1040s5nb15x7hx2cqmyw1jyi-qt-5.3.1/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so
```

Again the output says nothing about `/nix/store` and `/nix/store/33xkmx1f1040s5nb15x7hx2cqmyw1jyi-qt-5.3.1`. Long story short I suggest to reconsider the problem and think what you really want to achieve. Perhaps simple `readlink [-f]` or `realpath [-e]` is enough?

Comment: The question is about reporting symbolic links, which your script doesn't do except when they're a component of the initial path.

Comment: @Gilles See the edit of my answer. I agree that this doesn't report about all symbolic links, but OP didn't specify exactly which path components should be followed. I think my answer solves at least part of the problem.