# How could I quickly find a recursive symbolic link?

Tags: find, symlink, recursive

I am experiencing an issue with a indexing program running much longer than expected.  I want to rule out the possibility of a recursive symbolic link.  How could I find a symbolic link that is recursive at some level?

Comment: [previously](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99159/is-there-an-algorithm-to-decide-if-a-symlink-loops), [previously](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79571/symbolic-link-recursion-what-makes-it-reset)

Comment: @JeffSchaller, The first link does detect recursive symbolic links.  Thank you for pointing me to that.  I saw the second question you linked before posting this question.  That does not provide a way to find such a link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99166/83205), provides a way to identify a recursive symbolic link using the `find` command:

```
$ find -L . 
.
./a
./a/b
./a/b/c
./a/b/c/d
find: File system loop detected; `./a/b/c/d/e' is part of the same file system loop as `./a/b'.
find: `./a/b/e': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Comment: can you filter out only those results?

Comment: Yes, the loop messages come out on stderr, so you can filter out only those results by running `find -L . > /dev/null`