# Error opening directory with Okular due to "Too many levels of symbolic links" in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, directory, symlink, pdf

```
This location could not be displayed.

Sorry, could not display all the contents of "Documents": Error opening directory '/home/arijit/Documents': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 for the second time. Upon installing the Okular PDF reader from the Snap Store, I encountered the above-mentioned problem. Please take a look at the issue; I suspect it may be related to the PDF reader installation.

Comment: run `ls -l /home/arijit/Documents`, what does it return, that path seems to be a symbolic link to some other file/directory, which is then probably symlink to another file/directory.

Comment: possibly/probably a symlink loop - e.g. a symlink in or under /home/arijit/Documents that points to /home/arijit/Documents. Some programs (e.g. `find`) can identify loops like this and deal with them, others don't (probably because it never occurred to the programmer).  BTW, see [Is there an algorithm to decide if a symlink loops?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99159/is-there-an-algorithm-to-decide-if-a-symlink-loops) and [How do I find circular symbolic links?](https://serverfault.com/questions/265598/how-do-i-find-circular-symbolic-links)

Comment: try running `find -L /home/arijit/Documents -type l -ls` - if there's a symlink loop, find will tell you.