# Get maximum level of symlinks

Tags: linux, symlink

I would like to get the number of maximum possible symlink level in the system. I found that it is hardcoded in the kernel to be 40. But I would like to get this number dynamically, in case someone changes this in the source code and recompiles the kernel. Is this even possible? And if not, how bad idea it is to assume this number to be always 40?

Thanks.

Comment: See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53087/86440) (which I’m not suggesting as a duplicate to avoid the hammer).

Answer (score 1):

```
touch file
test_max=45
for ((j=2,i=3;i<test_max;i++,j++)) ; do ln -s $j $i; done
for ((i=1;i<test_max;i++)) ; do if ! [ -f "$i" ]; then echo "$i"; break; fi ; done
41
```

Comment: Is this really the only option?

Comment: @karlosss That is not my claim. I wasn't even aware of the problem until I read your question. That was my spontaneous idea how to get that information. But it may be available somewhere explicitly (I didn't find anything in `/proc/sys/kernel/`, though).

Comment: The closest you can get is `echo -n "#include <sys/param.h>\nMAXSYMLINKS" | gcc -E -`, but that gives the C library’s version, not the kernel’s (20 v. 40). There’s nothing in `getconf`. Some Unix systems had this as a kernel tunable (`fs_symlinks` IIRC on HP-UX).

Comment: I am still hoping (yeah, the probability is very low) that we are all missing something and somebody will come with a shell variable or a file containing this value. I would like to avoid the `gcc` solution as well.

Comment: On my OpenBSD system, I can do `getconf SYMLOOP_MAX` to get back "32".

Comment: On ArchLinux, I get `undefined` from this, whatever it means.

Comment: Yes, `SYMLOOP_MAX` is undefined on Linux (`sysconf` knows about the name but returns -1). The documentation says this means that “there is no definite limit”. (Funnily enough, when I wrote ”There’s nothing in `getconf`” earlier I was staring at the “undefined” output...)