# Does lsof always show the resolved absolute pathnames of opened files

Tags: lsof

In the output of `lsof`, does the `NAME` column always output the resolved absolute pathnames of opened files  (resolved in the sense of no symlink, `.` or `..` in the pathname)?

For example, if I `cd` into some symlink to a directory, and then run a program to open a file under that directory, does `lsof` only show the resolved absolute pathname of the file?

Can I make `lsof` output the unresolved absolute pathnames of opened files (unresolved in the sense that directory symlinks should appear in pathnames)?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

Without options, it should provide pathnames in resolved form. From [lsof(8) manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof):

> An open file may be a regular file, a directory, a block special file, a character special file, an executing text reference, a library, a stream or a network file (Internet socket, NFS file or UNIX domain socket.) A specific file or all the files in a file system may be selected by path.

There can of course be errors, such as [pathname too long](https://github.com/Distrotech/lsof/blob/c04923d4e1a2b40dc07eb4e024a810d4d01ea944/misc.c#L1065), in which case pathname won't be resolved, but otherwise `lsof` relies apparently on a [wrapper function around `readlink()`](https://github.com/Distrotech/lsof/blob/c04923d4e1a2b40dc07eb4e024a810d4d01ea944/misc.c#L419), which should do the job.

If you do specify a filename as in `lsof [options] [--] names`, it should be resolved:

> names
>   These are path names of specific files to list. Symbolic links are resolved before use. The first name may be separated from the preceding options with the ''--'' option.

Of course, standard rules for resolving filenames apply. Too many levels of symlinks [will result in an error](https://github.com/Distrotech/lsof/blob/c04923d4e1a2b40dc07eb4e024a810d4d01ea944/misc.c#L1173). `lsof` relies on MAXSYMLINKS variable  [hardcoded in the Linux kernel to max level of 40 symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53107/85039), and [for other systems where the variable is undefined - sets that to 32](https://github.com/Distrotech/lsof/blob/c04923d4e1a2b40dc07eb4e024a810d4d01ea944/misc.c#L51).

If you do specify `-b` option, filenames won't be resolved:

> Third, if the names of your file system directories that lsof obtains from your system's mount table are symbolic links, lsof won't be able to resolve the links. This is because the -b option causes lsof to avoid the kernel readlink(2) function it uses to resolve symbolic links.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why `lsof -b`  still show resolved pathnames.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a socket file in use should count as an open file, but in the case of unix domain sockets, `lsof` will only list as `NAME` (and is only able to find by) the *exact* name a socket was bound to, whether that's a relative or absolute path, and with any path artifacts left unchanged:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ nc -dUl ./././///sock &
[3] 6324
$ ls sock /tmp/sock ./sock
./sock  /tmp/sock  sock
$ lsof sock /tmp/sock ./sock
[nothing]
$ lsof ./././///sock
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
nc      6324  XXX    3u  unix 0xffff9f9faab76000      0t0 175260 ./././///sock type=STREAM
```

Notice that in the case of a **non-abstract** unix domain socket, the path the socket was bound or connected to matters only until the kernel has resolved it; it's the [device,inode] tuple which is the real address the socket is bound or connected to:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ nc -dUl ./././///sock &
[1] 7293
$ mv sock SOCK
$ lsof -aUp $!
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
nc      7293   xxx    3u  unix 0xffff908d70bb5800      0t0 1137631 ./././///sock type=STREAM
$ lsof ./././///sock
lsof: status error on ./././///sock: No such file or directory
[stupid junk snipped]
$ lsof SOCK
[nothing]
$ nc -U ./././///sock
nc: unix connect failed: No such file or directory
$ nc -U SOCK
[connected ok]
```

`lsof` is also not able to find datagram sockets "connected" (ie. with their default send address set) to another socket, is making impossible to distinguish abstract sockets with a `@` in their name from those with a NUL byte in their name, etc.

Just in case someone's wondering, all the needed info is available via the `sock_diag` interface (`UDIAG_SHOW_VFS`, `UDIAG_SHOW_PEER` look at the `linux/unix_udiag.h` header); it's just that `lsof` is too dumb to make use of it.

Note: the examples are using the `nc` from the `netcat-openbsd` package from Debian, which supports Unix sockets.